# kernel module error: implicit declaration of function

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I'm trying to write 2 simple kernel modules: `acumulator.c` and `client.c`.

acumulator.c has 2 function : `void acumulate();` and `int consult();` plus the `init_module` and the `cleanup_module`. 
The `acumulate` function increments the value of variable `acumulador` by 1 every time it's invoked, and the `consult` function returns the current value of the variable `acumulador`.

Those 2 functions are invoked within the module `Client.c`.

`Client.c` has only the `init_module()` and the `cleanup_module`, when the `init_module` starts, it calls the `acumulate` function and the `consult` function which are implemented within `acumulator.c`

When I compile the files: `acumulator.c` it compiles without error but `client.c` gives me 2 errors:

```
Implicit declaration of function acumulate()
Implicit declaration of function consult()
```

I don't know how I can fix this.

my kernel version is 2.6.38

The code of `acumulator.c` is:

```
static int acumulador = 0;

void acumulate() {
   acumulador += 1;
}

int consult() {
   return acumulador;
}

int init_module() {
    printk("\loading  module acumulator\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() {
    printk("\unloading  modul acumulator\n");
}
```

and the code of `Client.c` is

```
int init_module() 
{
    acumulate();
    printk("\loading module client:\Acumulate Value is = %d\n", consult());
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() 
{
    printk("\unloading modul client\n");
}
```

Comment: Please show the commands you are using to compile the code. Please also make sure you copied the contents of the files as is, with the correct names. From what you wrote I suppose you should `#include` a header file with function declarations into `client.c`.

Comment: i'm using makefile :
first i commpile acumulador.c 

obj-m = acumulador.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

and then i modify the same makefile changing acumulador.o by cliente.o

Comment: my code of make file is :
`obj-m = acumulador.o 
 all: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules     
 clean: make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean`  

fisrt i compile acumulador.o and i modif the same makefile to compile client.o